# How to use SQL Server inside Docker container on dev. environment in a correct way

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I'm going to move .NET project into containers and want to do this in a correct way.
At the moment development environment is a simple:

- Each developer has his-own SQL Server deployed on his PC and all DB lives there
- During development  ASP.NET project runs in IIS Express
- Connection string to connect to DB looks like this "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DB;Trusted_Connection=True". Using "." as data source helps unify web.config and have it working on each developer's PC

Everything is simple.

Right now because of many reasons I would like to move into containers and faced with few issues. All of them I think because of my misunderstanding of some principle of the containers and that is why I need somebody small help to avoid waste of time doing wrong things.

The main issues linked with working with DB

1. How to create a container with SQL Server and list of DB to be able
   to work with it on the same way how we work with it right now. I
   mean - OS is started, SQL server service is started and I can
   connect to DB via MS Management Studio. The main concern is a having
   all DB in safe. I've understood how to mount volume with persistence
   storage to have Backup creation on it. But can I work on the same way with DB to be sure that each time when container starts I have all DB working?
2. How I can then configure docker-compose file in project's solution
   to connect to that container with working DB and don't start new
   one?
3. And how to do this on the way to have connection string the same on each developer's PC? I mean - avoid having IP address as data source and still works with "." or "localhost" or something which could be the same for everyone?
4. If my understand of containers is incorrect and I should use
   deployed in my PC SQL server - how to configure docker-compose file
   to connect to SQL server in the host via "localhost" avoiding
   defining IP address or make it works the same on each PC?

How to make it works then on production I know because we have there one SQL Server with the only one connection string and it's not an issue. But how to configure dev. environment - it's a question for me. And 1 week guides reading really didn't help. Maybe I missed something and somebody could just point to correct article which could give me some answers.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

## Docker Compose for Sql Server

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
    app-mssql:
        image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
        # volumes are not supported on macOS
        # uncomment bellow volume and replace volume with relative or absolute path of the host
        # volumes:
        #     - ~/volumes/jhipster/tempdb/mssql/:/var/opt/mssql/data/
        environment:
            - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
            - SA_PASSWORD=yourStrong(!)Password
        ports:
            - 1433:1433
```

### Requirements:

RAM :  2GB

### Environment Variables

```
  ACCEPT_EULA=Y

  SA_PASSWORD=<your_strong_password>

  MSSQL_PID=<your_product_id | edition_name> (default: Developer)
```

**ACCEPT_EULA** confirms your acceptance of the End-User Licensing Agreement.

**SA_PASSWORD** is the database system administrator (userid = 'sa') password used to connect to SQL Server once the container is running. Important note: This password needs to include at least 8 characters of at least three of these four categories: uppercase letters, lowercase letters, numbers and non-alphanumeric symbols.

**MSSQL_PID** is the Product ID (PID) or Edition that the container will run with.

> Acceptable values:
>
> **Developer** : This will run the container using the Developer Edition (this is the default if no MSSQL_PID environment variable is supplied)
>
> **Express** : This will run the container using the Express Edition
>
> **Standard** : This will run the container using the Standard Edition
>
> **Enterprise** : This will run the container using the Enterprise Edition
>
> **EnterpriseCore** : This will run the container using the Enterprise Edition Core
>
> ***valid product id*** : This will run the container with the edition that is associated with the PID

***NOTE : Here you can find the detiled documentation on docker hub [microsoft/mssql-server-linux](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/)***